# Add actionperformed to a button through another class

Tags: java, class, jbutton, actionlistener, class-method

I'm trying to learn methods and classes
I created a small tool where class Main is to run it, class SWing to create the frame, class Verb to create a button to add to Swing and as well to do the action performed, my question here is that, how can I make the action performed really works via verb Class.
let's say I want to get text from textfield and to concatenate it with textfiled1 and to show the answer on textfield2.
here is my code

1- my main class

```
package Abo;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args){
            Swing runFrame = new Swing(); // creating a variable for class Swing 
            runFrame.Run(); // to run the Swing
    }
}
```

2- my Swing

```
package Abo;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Swing extends JFrame {
    public JTextField textField;
    public JTextField textField_1;
    public JTextField textField_2;

    public Swing() { 
        // creating the frame
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

            textField = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            textField_1 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(textField_1);
            textField_1.setColumns(10);

            textField_2 = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(textField_2);
            textField_2.setColumns(10);
            textField_2.setEditable(false);

            // adding the btn from another class
            Verb addBTN = new Verb();
            getContentPane().add(addBTN.BTN());


    }

    public void Run(){
        // setting the frame
            Swing frame = new Swing();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(300,400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
    }
}
```

3- verb class

```
package Abo;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Verb extends JButton {


// creating the btn constructor
    public JButton BTN(){
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("First Button");
        return btn1;
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Where does Verb extend JButton? It seems kind pointless to exerted from JButton and create another JButton within in. I think you might want to look at the Action class

Comment: May be I did a mistake by using extends, I'm not experience with it at all, just was trying, I prefer as well to create the button myself, so I can remove the extension.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by having a look at [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and for something a little more advanced [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well in your verb class just add this to btn1

```
 btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //Execute when button is pressed



                }
            });
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it didn't work, the button don't do any actions

 I added it inside  the JButton BTN

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `Verb` is extending `JButton`, but you are opting to write a method that returns a `JButton` inside of it.

If you want `Verb` to be a `JButton` that is always called `"First Button"`, then I would instead modify `Verb`'s constructor.

One way to do that would be like this:

```
package Abo;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Verb extends JButton {
    public Verb() {
        super("First Button"); //super calls the constructor of the parent of this class, in this case that is JButton
    }
}
```

Now since you are extending `JButton`, whenever you make a `Verb`, it will also be a `JButton` with the text `"First Button"`

Now you can add your `ActionListener` to `Verb` directly.

By doing:

```
Verb addBTN = new Verb();
addBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField_2.setText(textField.getText() + textField_1.getText());
    }
});
```

However, in order to access your text fields inside of the actionlistener, you will need to make them final.

`final textField = new JTextField(); // do this for all text fields`

Also, just as good practice, unless you are planning to add more functionality than the default constructor to `Verb`, I would just use a `JButton` instead of making your own class.

Comment: Thank you so much
But then How I will add the button to SWING?
PLZ note that the classes are not in one java file, every class is in a separate java file

Comment: getContentPane().add(addBTN);

Comment: Verb is now a subclass of JButton, so everything you can do with a JButton you can do with a Verb